# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') in ReactNative

Tags: reactjs, react-native, foreach, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to map through my string array, but I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

```
function AmountOfChoicesListComponent() {
        const amountOfChoices = ['första', 'andra', 'tredje', 'fjärde', 'femte'];

        return (
            <View>
                {amountOfChoices.map((text) => (
                    <>
                    <Title>{text}</Title>
                    <ChoicesComponent />
                    </>
                ))}
            </View>
        );
    }
```

My array has a value from the beginning. I have tried to use a `forEach` instead but nothing shows on the screen. I have tried to make the variable into a `useState` and I get the same error.

When I log the array inside of a `useEffect` like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(firebaseAction.geDataFS(docName));   
        console.log("MY ARRAYYYYYY: ", amountOfChoices)  
    }, []);
```

my console.log shows my array. I have missed something very small, but I cant seem to understand why I get this error.

Comment: I see no possible way for the error you see to come from the code you've shared. `amountOfChoices` is const and never mutated/updated. Are you ***sure*** this is the code causing the issue? Can you create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: An other comment is when you map through stuff in react/react-native you must give each component a unique key.  Read more here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70222526/how-can-i-resolve-this-warning-encountered-two-children-with-the-same-key/70222649#70222649)

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading the data asynchronously, you could always test `amountOfChoices` array to see if it exists and/or has length > 0 before rendering your markup.

If you just want to suppress the error on your first render, you could try changing your map to use the Optional Chaining operator: `amountOfChoices?.map(...)`.