# In React, can a component return the results of array.map without the empty element wrapper <> </>?

Tags: reactjs

I'm extremely new to React and following this tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7ejDZ8SWv8 (~42 minute mark)

I know that you can't return multiple elements from a component, otherwise it will throw an error (and in fact I've tested this and seen it). The way to return multiple elements is to use the empty element <> </> as a wrapper. This makes sense to me so far.

In the tutorial I'm following, he follows this exact pattern:

```
const Tasks = () => {
    return (
       <>
         { tasks.map((task) => (<h3>{task.text}</h3>)) }
       </>
    )
}
```

My problem, is I'm not doing that and it's still working. My understanding is that my code below would return an array of `h3` 's. But does React treat this as one element? If so, why did the tutorial bother to use the wrapper? (unless this is a newer feature or they just weren't aware).

```
const Tasks = () => {
    return (
        tasks.map((task) => (<h3>{task.text}</h3>))
    )
}
```

Comment: You need the `{}` when using javascript inside jsx. And you need to pass a key to each component when mapping through it. More about keys here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70222526/how-can-i-resolve-this-warning-encountered-two-children-with-the-same-key/70222649#70222649)

Comment: The wrapper isn't needed if the returned array is the only top-level element

Comment: Returning an array of elements (component or string) is perfectly fine, React renders them in order, but you should give each component element a key. You may find that some parent components you use require a single child but that's a separate issue.

Comment: I understand the key requirement. I didn't include that because it's not relevant to whether or not the component renders. Thank you for the answers.